# Aligning several '=' symbols across two lines

Tags: vertical-alignment

I'd like to write two lines of equations, each containing two '`=`' symbols, in such a way that the corresponding '`=`' symbols will be vertically aligned.

I tried using the `align` environment thus:

```
\begin{align*}
  P^{-1}AP & = P^T\left[\lambda_1p_1, \dots, \lambda_np_n\right] & = \left[\lambda_1P^Tp_1, \dots, \lambda_nP^Tp_n\right]
  \\ & = \left[\lambda_1i_1, \dots, \lambda_ni_n\right] & = \textrm{diag}\left(\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n\right)
\end{align*}
```

But this produced [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8PMF.jpg) where the second '`=`' symbols are not aligned. Why aren't they aligned? How can I align them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `alignat*` environment does it for you with two alignment characters (`&`) in front of the equal signs.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
  \begin{alignat*}{2}
    P^{-1}AP & = P^T\left[\lambda_1p_1, \dots, \lambda_np_n\right] && = \left[\lambda_1P^Tp_1, \dots, \lambda_nP^Tp_n\right] \\
    & = \left[\lambda_1i_1, \dots, \lambda_ni_n\right] && = \textrm{diag}\left(\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n\right)
  \end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

**Further reading**

- The »[Math mode](http://ctan.org/pkg/voss-mathmode)« document

---

[image]

---

**Addendum**

For comparison without automatically scaled delimiters and "diag" as operator.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\diag}{diag}

\begin{document}
  \begin{alignat*}{2}
    P^{-1}AP &= P^T [\lambda_1p_1, \dots, \lambda_np_n] &&= [\lambda_1P^Tp_1, \dots, \lambda_nP^Tp_n] \\
    &= [\lambda_1i_1, \dots, \lambda_ni_n] &&= \diag(\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n)
  \end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

---

[image]

Comment: It would be better if you removed the useless `\left` and `\right` and turned `\textrm{diag}` into `\operatorname{diag}`.

Comment: @egreg: These are not my idea and just copied from the question. And by the way, they can also be found in the other answer. The same applies to "diag". Your comment would be more appropriate to the question.

Comment: @egreg: Why are the \left and \right useless? Do they have any cons? What would be a suitable circumstance to use them?

Comment: @EvanAad They just add unwanted space, and slightly increase the size in the part above “diag”, which unbalances the display.

Comment: @egreg: I always use \left and \right with brackets and braces. I do it for the following reason. I once took a programming course and I was taught that even though it's legal to use an "if" statement without braces, I should always use braces, because even if today the "if" body consists of only a single statement, in the future I may add to it and then I might forget to add the braces. So extra braces don't hurt and they may save some headache in the future. This is why I use them in LaTeX too. As Thorsten Donig shows above, there's hardly any difference in the output with or without \left.

Comment: @EvanAad then use `mleftright` package (see [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/oberdiek/mleftright.pdf)).

Comment: @EvanAad This is a completely different situation: `\left` and `\right` should be used only when really necessary. Do as you prefer, of course, but in this particular case the difference in height is noticeable and surely unnecessary.

Answer (score 5):

You need two `&`. The first of the two is for the left part (here empty) of the second equation system:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  P^{-1}AP & = P^T\left[\lambda_1p_1, \dots, \lambda_np_n\right] && =
 \left[\lambda_1P^Tp_1, \dots, \lambda_nP^Tp_n\right]
  \\
  & = \left[\lambda_1i_1, \dots, \lambda_ni_n\right] && =
 \textrm{diag}\left(\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n\right)
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]